# Open all results from a search in a text editor

Tags: powershell, vim

I would like to create a function that will search for a string and open all results in vim.

In powershell I have:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -filter *.cs | Select-String -pattern $str | group path | select name
```

$str is the string I'm searching for.

Now I would like to redirect all the results to vim. Piping results to vim gives error that output for vim is not the console so it doesn't work.

How can I redirect results to vim or any other text editor?

**EDIT:** Added vim tag, because there might be an option to do it in vim instead of using powershell.

Comment: Write the results to a file and open that file in Vim.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers If I pipe to "| vim - " I get all the file names in vim, but I want all the files open in buffers (or tabs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Vim-only solution:

```
:vim foo **/*.cs | cw
```

It doesn't open every file but you get a much more useful interactive list called "quickfix window" that lets you jump to the right line in the right file.

See `:help :vimgrep` and `:help quickfix-window`.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use your command in the `set grepprg` command.

Check `:help grepprg` (You'll probably also need to replace the default shell on Windows from cmd to Powershell)

The good part of using grepprg is that it display the list of results into a Quicklist (copen/cclose).